# Getting error when passing object in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting error when passing object in onclick event [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/9/)

```
(function() {
  function a() {
    var x = [{
      "name": "main",
      "data": {"name":'john'}
    }, {
      "name": "sub",
      "data": {"name":'guru'}
    }, {
      "name": "lower",
      "data": {"name":'jack'}
    }]
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      var data = "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>main </span>";
      data += "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>sub </span>"
      data += "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>lower</span><br>"
      $('#data').prepend(data);
    }
  }
  a()
})()
```

Comment: Check the web-inspector, th html is rendering as `onclick="getInfo([object Object])"`. You should preferably use javascript or jQuery click handlers.

Comment: share the getInfo() function.

Comment: you have to stringify and pass the parameter
check this working solution https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/fddr0bnv/29/

Answer (score 2):

You should change way in which your data is generated to this:

```
var data = "<span onclick='getInfo(" + JSON.stringify(x[i].data) + ")'>main </span>";
```

Without this html that is generated is this:

```
<span onclick="getInfo([object Object])">main </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to assign an object rather its name so that was causing the error. Try it this way

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var data = "<span onclick='getInfo(\"" + x[i].data.name + "\")'>main </span>";
  data += "<span onclick='getInfo(\"" + x[i].data.name + "\")'>sub </span>"
  data += "<span onclick='getInfo(\"" + x[i].data.name + "\")'>lower</span><br>"
  $('#data').prepend(data);
}
```

Better use `Jquery` onclick function something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var data = "<span data-name='\"" + x[i].data.name + "\"' class='notify'>main</span>";
  data += "<span data-name='\"" + x[i].data.name + "\"' class='notify'>sub </span>"
  data += "<span data-name='\"" + x[i].data.name + "\"' class='notify'>lower</span><br>"
  $('#data').prepend(data);
}

$(document).on('click', '.notify', function(e) {   console.log($(this).attr('data-name')); });
```

[Jquery Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/25/)

Or as Suggest by @Nemanja Todorovic you can cast Json to string

```
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       var data = "<span data-info='\"" + JSON.stringify(x[i].data)  + "\"' class='notify'>main</span>";
       data += "<span data-info='\"" + JSON.stringify(x[i].data) + "\"' class='notify'>sub </span>"
       data += "<span data-info='\"" + JSON.stringify(x[i].data) + "\"' class='notify'>lower</span><br>"
       $('#data').prepend(data);
    }

 $(document).on('click', '.notify', function(e) {   console.log($(this).attr('data-info')); });
```

[Final Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/28/)